# How can I use GroupLayout to indent?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

Why doesn't the following code indent label `c2`?

```
JPanel ep = new JPanel();
            GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout( ep );
            ep.setLayout( gl );
            gl.setAutoCreateGaps( true );
            gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps( true );

            JLabel c1 = new JLabel( "c10000000" );
            JLabel c2 = new JLabel( "c20000000" );
            Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder( Color.black );
            c1.setBorder( b );
            c2.setBorder( b );

            gl.setHorizontalGroup( gl.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent( c1 )
                    .addComponent( c2 )
                    );
            gl.setVerticalGroup( gl.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap( c1, c2, ComponentPlacement.INDENT )
                    .addComponent( c1 )
                    .addComponent( c2 )
                    );
```

the result of this code is this

[image: Screenshot]

The line `.addPreferredGap( c1, c2, ComponentPlacement.INDENT )`
should indent the second component but it does not. Can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it shouldn't. The vertical group goes VERTICALLY down the screen. So, in this case, it goes:

```
Gap -> c1 -> c2
```

If you want to indent the second element, you need to create a sequential group for the second row in your **horizontal group**, to say "first a gap, then an element". This would be something like:

```
gl.setHorizontalGroup( gl.createParallelGroup()
        .addComponent( c1 )
        .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addPreferredGap(c1, c2, ComponentPlacement.INDENT)
            .addComponent( c2 )
            )
        );
gl.setVerticalGroup( gl.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent( c1 )
        .addComponent( c2 )
    );
```

Result:

[image]